# Not able to log in in SNOWSQL using windows console

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to access Snowflake using SNOWSQL in windows console.

While doing this, I give full credentials, including region:

```
snowsql -a XXXXXX.europe-west4.gcp -u XXXXX;
```

When asked for password, I enter the correct password (double checked this in the Snowflake web UI).

After confirming, I get the error message:

> 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB:
> XXXXXXX.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect
> username or password was specified.

This morning, I was still able to log in using the above statement. Can this be related to setting, incorrect closing,...?

I pasted the content of my log file below

```
2022-04-11 08:08:03,136 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.util_cli DEBUG       util_cli:686  - Initialized logging. Log file 'C:\\Users\\Bounce\\.snowsql\\log', Namespaces: ['snowflake.cli', 'snowflake.connector', 'botocore', 'azure', '__main__', 'eventloop', 'sqlexecute']
2022-04-11 08:08:03,136 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.util_cli INFO       util_cli:722  - REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE is already set to C:\Users\Bounce\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI100082\certifi\cacert.pem
2022-04-11 08:08:03,136 (10772/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:209  - is_terminal: True, is_interactive: True
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.sqlexecute DEBUG     sqlexecute:163  - starting sqlexecute
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.config DEBUG         config:87   - Reading cnf: C:\Users\Bounce\.snowsql\1.2.21\snowsql.cnf
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.config DEBUG         config:87   - Reading cnf: /etc/snowsql.cnf
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.config DEBUG         config:87   - Reading cnf: /etc/snowflake/snowsql.cnf
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.config DEBUG         config:87   - Reading cnf: /usr/local/etc/snowsql.cnf
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.config DEBUG         config:87   - Reading cnf: C:\Users\Bounce\.snowsql.cnf
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.common.config DEBUG         config:87   - Reading cnf: C:\Users\Bounce\.snowsql\config
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:353  - [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:359  - fallback to config values only if user did not specify a value and sqlexecute is connecting for the first time.
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:407  - host=None, port: + None
2022-04-11 08:08:03,152 (10772/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:446  - prompting user, password and account if still missing
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:501  - init sqlexecute
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.sqlexecute DEBUG     sqlexecute:254  - Connection DB Params: database: None, warehouse: None, user: xxxxxxxxx;, host: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com, port: 443, region: None, account: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp, protocol: https, schema: None, role: None, ocsp_fail_open: True, insecure_mode: None, proxy_host: None, proxy_port: None, proxy_user: None, authenticator: SNOWFLAKE, session_parameters: {'ABORT_DETACHED_QUERY': False}, login_timeout: 120, client_session_keep_alive: False, disable_request_pooling: None, client_store_temporary_credential: None
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.connection INFO     connection:272  - Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 2.7.1, Python Version: 3.6.8, Platform: Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP0
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.connection DEBUG     connection:489  - connect
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.connection DEBUG     connection:754  - __config
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.connection INFO     connection:879  - This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity.
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.connection INFO     connection:896  - Setting use_openssl_only mode to False
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.converter DEBUG      converter:142  - use_numpy: False
2022-04-11 08:08:10,693 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.connection DEBUG     connection:657  - REST API object was created: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.auth DEBUG           auth:170  - authenticate
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.auth DEBUG           auth:200  - assertion content: *********
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.auth DEBUG           auth:212  - account=xxxxxxx, user=xxxxxxxxx;, database=None, schema=None, warehouse=None, role=None, request_id=3799c227-4d7b-4773-a536-acda88856c54
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.auth DEBUG           auth:238  - body['data']: {'CLIENT_APP_ID': 'SnowSQL', 'CLIENT_APP_VERSION': '1.2.21', 'SVN_REVISION': None, 'ACCOUNT_NAME': 'xxxxxxx', 'LOGIN_NAME': 'xxxxxxxxx;', 'CLIENT_ENVIRONMENT': {'APPLICATION': 'SnowSQL', 'OS': 'Windows', 'OS_VERSION': 'Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP0', 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.6.8', 'PYTHON_RUNTIME': 'CPython', 'PYTHON_COMPILER': 'MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)', 'OCSP_MODE': 'FAIL_OPEN', 'TRACING': 10, 'LOGIN_TIMEOUT': 120, 'NETWORK_TIMEOUT': None}, 'SESSION_PARAMETERS': {'ABORT_DETACHED_QUERY': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE': False, 'CLIENT_PREFETCH_THREADS': 4}}
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.auth DEBUG           auth:254  - Timeout set to 120
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.util.retry DEBUG          retry:333  - Converted retries value: 1 -> Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.util.retry DEBUG          retry:333  - Converted retries value: 1 -> Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1117 - Session status for SessionPool 'xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com', SessionPool 1/1 active sessions
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:826  - remaining request timeout: 120, retry cnt: 1
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:804  - Request guid: 9fb618c7-60d4-45fb-8107-b409d048ba8c
2022-04-11 08:08:10,709 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:973  - socket timeout: 60
2022-04-11 08:08:10,725 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG connectionpool:975  - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443
2022-04-11 08:08:10,881 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:464  - cache directory: C:\Users\Bounce\AppData\Local\Snowflake\Caches
2022-04-11 08:08:10,990 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ssl_wrap_socket DEBUG ssl_wrap_socket:86   - OCSP Mode: FAIL_OPEN, OCSP response cache file name: None
2022-04-11 08:08:10,990 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:506  - ocsp_response_cache_uri: file://C:/Users/Bounce/AppData/Local/Snowflake/Caches/ocsp_response_cache.json
2022-04-11 08:08:10,990 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:507  - OCSP_VALIDATION_CACHE size: 0
2022-04-11 08:08:10,990 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:290  - OCSP response cache server is enabled: http://ocsp.snowflakecomputing.com/ocsp_response_cache.json
2022-04-11 08:08:10,990 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:325  - OCSP dynamic cache server RETRY URL: None
2022-04-11 08:08:11,006 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2025-05-12 23:58:59+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,006 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2024-05-12 02:43:45+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,021 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2024-05-12 02:47:38+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,021 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2025-05-12 23:58:59+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,037 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2025-05-12 23:58:59+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,115 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2022-05-15 00:00:00+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,131 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 20:00:20+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,146 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,146 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,146 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,162 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,162 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 20:00:20+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,178 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,178 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 20:00:20+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,178 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,193 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 20:00:20+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,193 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,193 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,209 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,209 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 20:00:20+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,209 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,225 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,225 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,225 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 20:00:20+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,240 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2023-01-25 19:35:21+00:00
2022-04-11 08:08:11,256 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:545  - Read OCSP response cache file: C:/Users/Bounce/AppData/Local/Snowflake/Caches/ocsp_response_cache.json, count=172
2022-04-11 08:08:11,256 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1063 - validating certificate: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com
2022-04-11 08:08:11,256 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:434  - # of certificates: 3
2022-04-11 08:08:11,256 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:440  - subject: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('state_or_province_name', 'California'), ('locality_name', 'San Mateo'), ('organization_name', 'Snowflake Inc.'), ('common_name', '*.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com')]), issuer: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('organization_name', 'DigiCert Inc'), ('common_name', 'DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1')])
2022-04-11 08:08:11,256 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:440  - subject: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('organization_name', 'DigiCert Inc'), ('common_name', 'DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1')]), issuer: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('organization_name', 'DigiCert Inc'), ('organizational_unit_name', 'www.digicert.com'), ('common_name', 'DigiCert Global Root CA')])
2022-04-11 08:08:11,271 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:440  - subject: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('organization_name', 'DigiCert Inc'), ('organizational_unit_name', 'www.digicert.com'), ('common_name', 'DigiCert Global Root CA')]), issuer: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('organization_name', 'DigiCert Inc'), ('organizational_unit_name', 'www.digicert.com'), ('common_name', 'DigiCert Global Root CA')])
2022-04-11 08:08:11,271 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:682  - hit cache for subject: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('state_or_province_name', 'California'), ('locality_name', 'San Mateo'), ('organization_name', 'Snowflake Inc.'), ('common_name', '*.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com')])
2022-04-11 08:08:11,271 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:682  - hit cache for subject: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('organization_name', 'DigiCert Inc'), ('common_name', 'DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1')])
2022-04-11 08:08:11,287 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:682  - hit cache for subject: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('state_or_province_name', 'California'), ('locality_name', 'San Mateo'), ('organization_name', 'Snowflake Inc.'), ('common_name', '*.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com')])
2022-04-11 08:08:11,287 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1237 - using OCSP response cache
2022-04-11 08:08:11,287 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:329  - Certificate is NOT attached in Basic OCSP Response. Using issuer's certificate
2022-04-11 08:08:11,287 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:336  - Verifying the OCSP response is signed by the issuer.
2022-04-11 08:08:11,350 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:682  - hit cache for subject: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('organization_name', 'DigiCert Inc'), ('common_name', 'DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1')])
2022-04-11 08:08:11,365 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1237 - using OCSP response cache
2022-04-11 08:08:11,365 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:329  - Certificate is NOT attached in Basic OCSP Response. Using issuer's certificate
2022-04-11 08:08:11,365 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:336  - Verifying the OCSP response is signed by the issuer.
2022-04-11 08:08:11,365 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:604  - writing OCSP response cache file to C:/Users/Bounce/AppData/Local/Snowflake/Caches/ocsp_response_cache.json
2022-04-11 08:08:11,365 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1715 - encoding OCSP response cache to JSON
2022-04-11 08:08:11,443 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1115 - ok
2022-04-11 08:08:11,490 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG connectionpool:461  - https://xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443 "POST /session/v1/login-request?request_id=3799c227-4d7b-4773-a536-acda88856c54&request_guid=9fb618c7-60d4-45fb-8107-b409d048ba8c HTTP/1.1" 200 427
2022-04-11 08:08:11,490 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1002 - SUCCESS
2022-04-11 08:08:11,490 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1123 - Session status for SessionPool 'xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com', SessionPool 0/1 active sessions
2022-04-11 08:08:11,490 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:713  - ret[code] = 390100, after post request
2022-04-11 08:08:11,490 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.auth DEBUG           auth:370  - completed authentication
2022-04-11 08:08:11,506 (10772/MainThread) __main__ ERROR      eventloop:547  - Database connection failed: 250001 (08001): None: Failed to connect to DB: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli\eventloop.py", line 540, in connect
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\cli\sqlexecute.py", line 296, in push_connection
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\__init__.py", line 50, in Connect
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 283, in __init__
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 494, in connect
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 733, in __open_connection
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 994, in _authenticate
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1026, in __authenticate
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\auth.py", line 409, in authenticate
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 273, in errorhandler_wrapper
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 327, in hand_to_other_handler
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 210, in default_errorhandler
snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 250001 (08001): None: Failed to connect to DB: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
2022-04-11 08:08:11,506 (10772/MainThread) __main__ INFO      eventloop:567  - rollback
2022-04-11 08:08:11,506 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.sqlexecute INFO     sqlexecute:368  - rollback
2022-04-11 08:08:11,506 (10772/MainThread) __main__ ERROR      eventloop:1248 - 250001 (08001): None: Failed to connect to DB: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli\eventloop.py", line 1183, in cli
  File "cli\eventloop.py", line 554, in connect
  File "cli\eventloop.py", line 540, in connect
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\cli\sqlexecute.py", line 296, in push_connection
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\__init__.py", line 50, in Connect
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 283, in __init__
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 494, in connect
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 733, in __open_connection
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 994, in _authenticate
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 1026, in __authenticate
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\auth.py", line 409, in authenticate
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 273, in errorhandler_wrapper
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 327, in hand_to_other_handler
  File "lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 210, in default_errorhandler
snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 250001 (08001): None: Failed to connect to DB: xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
2022-04-11 08:08:11,521 (10772/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:581  - closing sessions
2022-04-11 08:08:11,521 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.sqlexecute DEBUG     sqlexecute:349  - closing connections
2022-04-11 08:08:11,521 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.sqlexecute DEBUG     sqlexecute:316  - joining async exec
2022-04-11 08:08:11,521 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.sqlexecute DEBUG     sqlexecute:324  - waiting for async exec to finish...
2022-04-11 08:08:11,521 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.cli.sqlexecute DEBUG     sqlexecute:341  - all async queries finished.
2022-04-11 08:08:11,553 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.connection INFO     connection:509  - closed
2022-04-11 08:08:11,553 (10772/MainThread) snowflake.connector.connection DEBUG     connection:526  - Exception encountered in closing connection. ignoring...: 'SnowflakeConnection' object has no attribute '_telemetry'
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you were able to login with exactly these details earlier then either your password has been changed or your access has been revoked. Can you log into the Snowflake UI?

Comment: That's indeed the strange part: logging in with my webbrowser works perfectly fine (via https://xxxxxxx.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com + same username & password).

Comment: @bounce Can you add to your SnowSQL command **-o log_level=DEBUG** so we can get a bit more information on why you're getting that error?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Sergiu. Should I add **-o log_level_debug** at the end of my statement? If I do that, I get another error-message: _Invalid value is specified in config: log_level_ But I do have a log file, I will add the content in the main question.

Comment: It’s not log_level_debug, it’s log_level=DEBUG

Comment: Do you have a config file under /.snowsql that has the connection details to the account and which has the user details as well? Is this user local to snowflake or is it coming from an external IDP like Azure or Okta?